# IS4 webapi server as a consumer and provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .net core Web API which is following [this example](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) from IS4.  It all works fine as long as the IS4 service simply acts as a provider of tokens.  I want to use the service as a consumer too, as in the service itself exposes some endpoints like this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("authorised"), Authorize]
    public IActionResult Authorised()
    {
        return new JsonResult("hello world");
    }

    [HttpGet("unauthorised")]
    public IActionResult Unauthorised()
    {
        return new JsonResult("unauth hello world");
    }
}
```

The `unauthorised` calls works perfectly but the `authorised` calls don't work at all.  Even weirder is that Postman returns `404 Not Found`.

The IS4 logic (Startup.cs) looks as below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
                options.ApiSecret = "secret";
            });

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer(); // does .UseAuthentication inside
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Weirdly this used to work fine in the previous IS4 samples which were built using .net core 1.1.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        // Use default auth scheme (cookies)
        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                 options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
                options.ApiSecret = "secret";
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {                
                options.AddPolicy("ApiPolicy", policy =>
                {
                   policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Bearer");
                   policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                });
            });

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer(); // does .UseAuthentication inside
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Now in one of your controllers, use the `[Authorize("ApiPolicy")]` attribute on a controller method or the controller itself.